# Best practice to have another view/order on mobile/desktop with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am developing a dashboard with Bootstrap 4 (on top of Angular 5).
Now I can't get around of the following problem:

Let's say I have the following view on my desktop.
I simplified the code to make it more readable. The cards do contain more div's like card-title et cetera and are placed within Angular components.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
      <div class="card"  style="height: 300px"> 
        card1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
        card2
      </div>
      <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
        card3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the two cols are nicely placed right to the 'bigger' card (see 'Full page' on desktop). Now on mobile (and portrait tablets) the 'card2' and 'card3' are placed under each other but I want them next to each other.

I can do this by generating a new view for mobile only, but in my opinion this could be done easier so I do not have any code duplicates.. But I just don't know how!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
          <div class="card"  style="height: 300px"> 
            card1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-md-block">
          <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
            card2
          </div>
          <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
            card3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-none d-block d-md-none">
          <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
            card2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-none d-block d-md-none">
          <div class="card"  style="height: 150px">
            card3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does someone know's how to do this in a much cleaner way? 
I also tried putting the cards on the right in their own rows, but that creates the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the card 2 & card 3 in another `row`>`col`s, no reason for markup duplication.

https://www.codeply.com/go/AF4sManetn

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
            <div class="card" style="height: 300px">
                card1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="card" style="height: 150px">
                        card2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="card" style="height: 150px">
                        card3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Tried to split the right col in two rows but haven't tried this one yet! Thanks, it works :-)!